# Core Data: Sorting results from an abstract entity based on entity type

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings

Is it possible to sort results from Core Data based on the entity type, but:

- without resorting to adding a fake attribute called something like `entityType`, and
- without adversely affecting performance by using KVO/KVC tricks such as introducing `-(NSString*)typeOfEntity` or similar?

I currently have:

- `TradeDocument` as an abstract entity, with
- `QuoteTradeDocument` and `InvoiceTradeDocument` as entities based on it.

I want to display entity type and/or allow `NSTableView` to be sorted based on this.

I use Cocoa Bindings on OS X.

---

Note: I am explicitly trying to avoid faulting each object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ivan,

The only limit with an abstract entity is that you can't instantiate one. You can still fetch them. Then it is a rather simple matter of testing against which subclass each managed object is.

Sorting on type is not something a sort descriptor can do but a function can, as with `-sortUsingFunction:context:`.

Andrew

Comment: This, however, means each object will be faulted. I'm trying to avoid this. Since Core Data must store object type in SQLite, I'd very much like to know if there is a publicly-exposed way to use this as a sort criteria.

Comment: Ivan, you can read in objects without faulting them or populating the row cache. See -includesPropertyValues on NSFetchRequest. You will be able to introspect the kind of object with -isKindOfClass: without firing the fault. In other words, my answer above still works just fine. If you want the sort to happen in the SQLite, then I think you are out of luck. Andrew

Comment: Thanks. It's sad that Apple didn't think of this kind of sorting and apply it in SQLite. I'll probably have to put the fetch request into the NSArrayController in code, right? Your solution seems good, but I'll see if someone else provides a more optimal one, one that can use some sort of existing, indexed, data structures in the persistent store. If noone comes along, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Ivan, Core Data is something different from an ORM. As they say, it is an object graph manager. That SQLite is just one of several persistence mechanisms.

Comment: I'm fully aware of it. However, if SQLite backend can provide a possible optimization for restoring a part of the object graph, it would be interesting to use it.

Comment: I'm accepting the answer, in light of extended experience I had with Core Data in the meantime.

Comment: inside SQLite there is a column named `Z_ENT` which is basically the entity type, unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a documented way to sort based on it.

Comment: also, i was able to instantiate and persist abstract entity in my code, is this can't instantiate restriction enforced at all?

Comment: Tony, I don't know if it is enforced. That said, there are several storage types, each with perhaps different constraints. Just because it worked on a simple test does not mean you have a general answer. If you really wish, you can probably trap this yourself in the methods that fire as things are being fetched or created. Andrew